# Watch function is not firing after variable being passed through params

Tags: vue.js

I cannot get the watch function to fire when I pass the params from the First block of code below to the second. I am getting the params, as I can register it on a refresh, but it isn't getting watched.

**First Block**

```
<template>
   <router-link :to="{ name: 'page', params: { mus: mus } }">
    <q-btn
      filled
      label="Get"
  /></router-link>
 </template>
 <script>
    import { ref } from "vue";
    import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

export default {
  name: "otherName",

setup() {
   
   let mus = ref("variable to pass");


   return {
    mus
  };
  },
 };
</script>
```

**Second Block: Here is the code that receives the params:**

```
<script>
  import { ref, watch} from "vue";
  import { useRoute } from "vue-router";

  export default {
   name: "page",

  setup(props, { emit }) {
   
   const route = useRoute();
  
   watch(
     () => route.params.mus,
     () => {
       if (route.params.mus != undefined) {
      
        //do things
     }
   }
);

return {
 };
},
```

};

***Edit:*** I'm getting an error: "Extraneous non-props attributes (mus) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes." Referencing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68803137/vue-3-passing-array-warning-extraneous-non-props-attributes-were-passed-to-comp) has not yet worked -- the page is wrapped in div elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a route naming error on my part, but I had the route named wrong. I had named a primary route and not the component route.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `watch` is *lazy*, that is it will only fire when it detects a **change** and wont fire immediately with the initial value.

If you want the watch listener to fire immediately AND for all subsequent changes to the watched property then you should use `watchEffect`.

```js
watchEffect(() => {
  if (route.params.mus != undefined) {
    //do things
  }
})
```

Here, the callback will run immediately. During its execution, it will also automatically track `route.params.mus` as a dependency (similar to computed properties). Whenever `route.params.mus` changes, the callback will be run again.

[`watch` vs `watchEffect`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#watcheffect)

Comment: I appreciate it. It still isn't firing when the params is passed via link. It fires only on page reload. The page loads blank and the watchEffect function does not fire.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `{ deep: true }` like this:

```js
watch(
     () => route.params.mus,
     () => {
       if (route.params.mus != undefined) {
      
        //do things
     },
   { deep: true }
 })
```