# Vue3 pass the data from Parent to Child

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

I bumped into this error when trying to pass the data from parent to child.

```
vue@next:1616 [Vue warn]: Extraneous non-props attributes (parentdata) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes. 
  at <Child parentdata="Data From Parent" > 
  at <App>
```

My source code is here below, just simply pass the data to Child from Parent.

I guess this is related with text root nodes? if so how can I fix this?

```
<div id="app">
<child parentData="Data From Parent"></child>
</div>

<template id="child_comp">
    Child component test [[ parentData]]
</template>

<script>
    const Child = {
        props:['parentData'],
        template: '#child_comp',
        data (){
            return {
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.parentData);
        },
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]']  
    }

    Vue.createApp({
        components:{
            "child":Child,
        },
        methods:{
        }
    }).mount('#app')

</script>
```

Comment: You probably want `:parentData=""`, with the colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your template is placed directly in the HTML, the `parentData` cannot be bound and generates the warning.

You should bind it with `kebab-case` like this

```
<child parent-data="Data From Parent" ></child>
```

Check the Vue Docs [DOM Template Parsing Caveats](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dom-template-parsing-caveats) for details.

---

BTW, also good to know:

The warning comes while you component does not have a single root node.

To prevent the warning you can put a `<div>` around your component's content, like this:

```
<div>Child component test : [[ parentData ]]<br/></div>
```

Or use `inheritAttrs: false` to suppress it.

And here is a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68803707/2487565) clarifying the problem with the warning.

### Example

Here is the playground showing it. The first `parentData="Data From Parent"` generates the warning and does not work. The second `parentData="Data From Parent"` works.

```js
const Child = {
    props:['parentData'],
    template: '#child_comp',
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.parentData);
    },
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]']  
}
Vue.createApp({
    components:{
        "child": Child,
    }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">  
  <child parentData="Data From Parent" ></child>
  <child parent-data="Data From Parent" ></child>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="my-component">
</script>
<template id="child_comp">
    Child component test : [[ parentData ]]<br/>
</template>
```

Comment: Wow, it's quite tricky to understand.. Witouout your help, it takes so much time to understand. thankyou very much!