# Extraneous non-props attributes were passed to component but couldn't be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

**It's error message**
[[console messsage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEWFm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rxHE.png)
**It's my child component**

```
<template>
        <section v-for="item in jsonObject" :key="item">
            <div :class="item.className">
                <img :src="item.src" :alt="item.alt" :class="item.imgClassName">
                <h2 v-html="item.h2Text"></h2>
            </div>
        </section>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps } from "vue"
const jsonObject = defineProps(['jsonObject'])
</script>
```

**It's my parent component**

```
<template>
  <main>
    <main-top-section :jsonObject="jsonObject"/>
    <section id="news-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="news-inside">
                <div class="inside-container">
                    <div class="tab-pane">
                        <div class="news-container">
                            <News :newsObj="newsObj"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive } from "vue"
import { useRoute } from "vue-router"
import NewsForUs from "@/json/NewsForUs.json"
import News from "@/components/NewsBox/NewsBox.vue"
import MainTopSectionJSONData from "@/json/MainTopSectionData.json"
import MainTopSection from "@/components/MainPageSection/MainPageSection.vue"
const route = useRoute()
const newsObj = reactive(NewsForUs)
const mainObj = reactive(MainTopSectionJSONData.filter((item) => item.path == route.path))
const jsonObject = mainObj[0]
</script>
```

I'm getting the message in title when develop project with vue. But I don't understand why I got this message. Because I encapsulating all elements with the root element. Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue 3 passing array warning: Extraneous non-props attributes were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68803137/vue-3-passing-array-warning-extraneous-non-props-attributes-were-passed-to-comp)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<template>
        <section v-for="item in jsonObject" :key="item"> // you loop the section here
            <div :class="item.className">
                <img :src="item.src" :alt="item.alt" :class="item.imgClassName">
                <h2 v-html="item.h2Text"></h2>
            </div>
        </section>
</template>
```

*Because I encapsulating all elements with the root element.*

no your not, because you loop the `section` making it no root element, wrap the section with `div` or just make another element to loop instead of loop the `section`

also you dont have to import `defineProps` all vue macros are auto imported

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replies. I solved this problem. Cause of the problem, I defined the name of the child component incorrectly. It's not related to the root element :)

**Wrong**
import MainTopSection from "@/components/MainPageSection/MainPageSection.vue"

**True**

```
import MainTopSection from
```

"@/components/MainTopSection /MainTopSection.vue"